# Powershell Custom Cmdlet

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've got the following task:

Create a script (cmdlet) to output the network adapters information and properties. Must include the -Name switch allowing to immediately output info on a particular network adapter, the -File switch allowing to save the info to a file. Add an instruction to call with the -? switch.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a homework completion website.

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm just looking for an idea how to create a custom cmdlet